# wordpress plugin when adding a filter for the_content, loading same content from a file breaks the page

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Within a plugin I am adding a filter to catch and append to / update the content of a certain page. If I just explicitly write the markup out in the same function it works, but if I try to load the exact same content from a file it seems to break the page (jQuery issues I believe).

works

```
function custom_content($content) {
    $content = '<div>Hello World</div>'; 
    return $content;
}
```

doesn't without causing client side errors?

```
function custom_content($content) {
   $content = file_get_contents(plugins_url('/html/file.html', __FILE__));
   return $content;
}
```

contents of the html file

```
'<div>Hello World</div>;'
```

Just curious to know why this isn't the same. I am not attempting to load my own version of jQuery or anything. Both of these get loaded properly with add_filter, but if I try to use the second it doesn't work but the first does. My thought would be that the get_file_contents should only load those contents and resolve the reference before page is born?

EDIT: I see a bunch of jQuery ref errors on the page when I try to load contents from the file.

```
 $()... is not defined
```

Always appreciate the help!

Comment: What does `plugins_url('/html/file.html', __FILE__)` resolve to?

Comment: location of the file mentioned above. confirmed it is correct it is how I have loaded scripts and styles for this plugin.

Comment: have you tried echoing out `$content` to something to verify that it is reading the file correctly?  Also I should note that none of this you have provided is jQuery.

Comment: true, the error I am getting it seems, that jquery breaks on the client side as a result of this. I am not sure if that is directly or indirectly related, though I am not attempting to use my own version or anything.

Comment: If the file you are reading contains `'<div>Hello World</div>'` and that is what is being successfully read into that variable being returned then your php is effectively the same.  `$()` being undefined would not be directly related to this, and signifies that you are trying to use jQuery before it is included on the page, or your page is operating in noConflict mode and jQuery is not bound to the `$` variable.  You could try changing the `$` to `jQuery` to see if the error goes away.  If it does, that means you are in noConflict mode.

Comment: Which in my experience talking with people who do wordpress sites, most wordpress sites run jQuery in noConflict mode.

Comment: I failed to mention that this is in AWS dev env, and as it turns out they are the culprit. Interestingly enough it is their content that is getting injected into this no matter what I do (file names, content, etc), and the encoding and structure is wrong. It seems to be their login form or at least part of it that is getting inject in place of my content? I have a ticket in with them.